# FlowLayout & Model-View Pattern in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have **FlowLayout** implementation similar to [this one here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) and have a custom tile-like widget that I add as items to it. It looks and handles great but the concern I have is once I will have to add, say 100 tiles to it. Sometime i even may have to insert in-between, not just add to bottom. I think a good practice would be to implement **QAbstractItemView** but could not find good references to get an idea how to go about it. Has anyone did similar lately? Can you please be of help?

Comment: What is the problem with taking the FlowLayout-example and expanding it? If you want to insert items at a specific position, then just expand the given "void FlowLayout::addItem(QLayoutItem *item)" with an index for the row-to-insert (and use that). Why do you think it won't scale to 100 items?

Comment: I settled with QListView in icon mode.